# Query a Google Doc for the owner/creator

Tags: google-apps-script, google-docs

I've been looking at the Google Apps Script API documentation, and have not been able to find a class or method that can return whether a user looking at a document (not a spreadsheet) is the owner/creator, viewer, or collaborator. Is this possible given this API? If so, which class can this functionality be found in?

Comment: Excuse me but I think your question is somewhat unclear... As I understand 'can return whether a user looking at a document...' you where asking to see who it is right now (meaning live), not who is allowed to look at it.

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't clear enough. I should have stated that it is already assumed that the document is declared public. This is more about who has permission to edit the document rather than who can view it. While  I am not using the `getViewers` and `getEditors` methods, I did find some other useful methods in the API that are more geared toward what I'm doing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [File](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/class_file) class has the `getOwner` method. it's possible to find the required file by traversing files using the [DocList](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/class_docslist) service. Also the class has other methods `getViewers` and `getEditors`.